# How to change combobox display but not value

Tags: c#, wpf

Im Having a problem where when I try to update the display value of my combo box options it doesn't update the displayed selected option. I'm keeping the same value it returns, simply changing the display value for that option. Is there any way to do this?

Some View Model:

```
public class NestedViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region Fields

    private ToneAction selectedValue;
    private Collection<KeyValuePair<string, SomeEnum>> options;

    #endregion

    NestedViewModel(){
        var newOptions = new Collection<KeyValuePair<string, SomeEnum>>();
        foreach (SomeEnum e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnum)))
        {
            newOptions.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, SomeEnum>(Random.Next(), e));
        }
        vm.Options = newOptions
    }

    public SomeEnum SelectedValue
    {
        get { return selectedValue }
        set
        {
            if (selectedValue == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            selectedValue = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedValue));
        }
    }

    public Collection<KeyValuePair<string, SomeEnum>> Options
    {
        get { return options; }
        set
        {
            if (options == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            options = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Options));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

ViewWithComboBox.xaml

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Options}"
    SelectedValuePath="Value"
    DisplayMemberPath="Key"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedValue}"/>
```

some service.cs

```
public class SomeService{
    var vm = new NestedViewModel();
    vm.SelectedValue = options.Last().Value; //updates and display key in combo box correctly

    var newOptions = new Collection<KeyValuePair<string, SomeEnum>>();
    foreach (SomeEnum e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnum)))
    {
        newOptions.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, SomeEnum>(Random.Next(), e));
    }
    vm.Options = newOptions; //sets combo highlighted red and blank

    vm.SelectedValue = options.First().Value; //updates and display key in combo box correctly
}
```

Comment: Try out `<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Options, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    SelectedValuePath="Value"
    DisplayMemberPath="Key"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>`

Comment: Which bit doesn't work?

Comment: @Andy `vm.Options = newOptions` is where the issue is caused.

Comment: You set selectedValue which is the backing variable rather than the property. That's not going to raise property changed. Does that work?

Comment: @Andy good catch. That was an error in my example code, but not the problem I'm having in my production code.